# Looking for 'software web directory' package for own installation

Tags: project-management, lifecycle

Like this done in

- http://directory.fsf.org/
- http://www.ohloh.net/

so anyone in our company (include bosses) can look:

- what projects exist (good to have web search capability)
- who is primary mainteners, responsible employees
- provide CHANGES, latest version
- point to BTS (Trac/Mantis), VCS (SVN/Git/HG), Wiki, Mail list, NNTP, Night build, CI build, etc...
- may be provide some summary info based on activity on BTS/VCS (how many opened bugs, how often and who commit)

I don't need extra features as Wiki. and package must work with several existing sofware management/development tools, and does not restricted with Java/C#...

I look on WEB without happen as don't know gold "keywords". Search on StackExchange also don't show any result.

Some requested features available in *enterprise application architecture for project hosting* (like **KForge**, **FusionForge**, **GForge**) but thay too complex and dictate toolset for teams...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that all existing software directory project built in house and their sources are not released for public.

Look for most complete list of [software directories enabled site](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_free_software_project_directories) that I found. Only *OpenSymphony* provide sources of some components.

So complete lightweight solution does not exist currently.

I going to write own...